# NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification NSDeletedObjectsKey Objects no longer has references to related objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to respond to changes of certain `NSManagedObject`s that have been added, updated, or deleted.

I have an issue with the deleted objects, though: all relationships to other objects are now nil.

Is there a way to get this kind of notification before the object is affected this way?

Edit:

This is basically my delete code:

```
  [moc deleteObject:myObject];

  id saveBlock = ^{
      NSError *error = nil;
      BOOL     saved = NO;

     saved = [self save:&error];

    // error handling.
  };

  [moc performBlockAndWait:saveBlock];
```

Comment: [prepareForDeletion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#jumpTo_31)?

Comment: I just discovered this issue myself. I know this question is years old, but do you happen to remember what you found?

Comment: @SAHM I think I created a custom notification and posted that at the appropriate time, passing in the object in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to react to deletions then you should be listening for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and watch for the `NSDSeletedObjectsKey` come through as part of the notification.  That is the last chance before deletion to deal with them.

Comment: Do you mean `NSDeletedObjectsKey` ? I thought of that but according to the Apple docs there is no `userInfo` dictionary for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`.

Comment: You are correct, but you can ask the `NSManagedObjectContext` for all of the `-deletedObjects` during the notification and get them.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was able to get this working but the reference to parent object is nil too. I guess I'm going to have to write my own custom notification.

Comment: There is no reason for any relationships to be `nil` at that point unless you have done something when you were deleting the objects.  Can you show your delete code in your question?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you find a work-around? The relationship to parent object is nil, even in NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification. My code for deleting the object is very simple: just take the object from the table, and delete it.

Comment: It is not an issue to work around. At the point of `NSManagedObjectContextWillChangeNotification` no relationships will be broken by Core Data. I would suggest putting break points in your code and find out where they are being disconnected as it is something outside of the Core Data framework. Maybe you are using a third party wrapper around Core Data?

Comment: I notice that @MarcusS.Zarra is saying "WillChange", not "WillSave". Although there's no "WillChange" notification name defined that I can see.